# Pending for user input inside of constructor

Tags: java, constructor, user-input

I was thinking about how bad is that kind of practice, when you do so:

```
SomeConstructor(){
 Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
 a = sc.nextInt();
}
```

Java allowed me to do so, but I have never seen anyone wrote code like that, so the question is what problems can such a code create and if it is bad practice, explain me why please.

Comment: *"Java allowed me to do so"*. I don't think any language can be designed in such a manner that it will prevent all stupidness that people can do. If you want to do blocking user I/O in a constructor, why would the *language* prohibit you to do so?

Comment: This certainly would not conform to the "Separation of concerns" design principle.  I'm sure somebody with a better knowledge than I could explain this better however.

Comment: But this would follow the icecream (i dont know if it realy has this name but the java io streams follow this sort of nesting principle) pattern. but im wrong maybe so please correct me

Comment: To borrow from @ghostcat Simply: really really bad.  - if the constructor throws an Exception, then is the Object really constructed

Comment: @M. le Rutte, by saying so i meant that i am learning right now and i didn't find an answer for my question in google. How am i suppose to know what is NOT allowed if i only read what is good? I am newbie in that field, so be patient please, or otherwise i don't really see the point of your comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply: **really** bad.

The main purpose of a constructor is of course to intialize the newly created object. But: you very much prefer to **pass in** values.

Meaning: when you have a constructor read from standard in, that makes it close to impossible to easily unit test the corresponding class!

You want to follow the **single responsibility principle**. Like: one class is responsible for gathering input. *Another* class is then responsible for processing that input. Your approach will lead to a class that first fetches values to then work with them. And as said: you want to avoid that.

Comment: Thank you a lot. Really appreciate you for being polite and explained everything.

Comment: @roleveltv You are very welcome. Please let me know if there is anything I could add in order to also get my answer upvote-worthy, now that you reached upvote privileges.